# How to use brew in crontab

Tags: bash, crontab

I run an alias in my .zshrc file every day.

```
alias buou="brew update && brew outdated && brew upgrade"
```

I want to run it by crontab on my macOS v10.13.6

I made a file called brewupdate.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
brew update && brew outdated && brew upgrade
```

It works when I run it by `sh brewupdate.sh`

I created a crontab and run it at 11:32.

```
32 11 * * *  /Users/sokada/brewupdate.sh
```

When I check it.

```
cat /var/mail/sokada
...
...
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=sokada>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=sokada>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/sokada>
Message-Id: <20180809023200.F192E1388B5F@Shinichis-MacBook-Pro.local>
Date: Thu,  9 Aug 2018 11:32:00 +0900 (JST)

/Users/sokada/brewupdate.sh: line 2: brew: command not found
```

It gives an error `brew: command not found`.

Is there any way I can run this script through crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a path to my brewupdate.sh and it works now.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
brew update && brew outdated && brew upgrade
```

There are [more solutions to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622613/crontab-doesnt-execute-ioreg-on-my-mac).